# Socky connection failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification

I get this kind of log when ever i start socky server

```
>> Thin web server (v1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3001, CTRL+C to stop
Socky : sending : {"event":"socky:connection:established","connection_id":"1320836395810196"}
Socky : received : {"event":"socky:subscribe","channel":"bizcard-updated-2011nov09-115943","connection_id":"1320836395810196"}
Socky : sending : {"event":"socky:subscribe:failure","channel":"bizcard-updated-2011nov09-115943"}
```

I am using

```
gem 'socky-client', '0.5.0.beta1'
```

Actually I cant figure it out why socky:subscribe:failure ie socky is not able to subscribe.
I once ran it and the subscription is also successfully. But some how later on this kind of message is being displayed.

However Socky get the data put not able to send it

```
Socky : received : {"event"=>"event_name", "channel"=>"channel name", "timestamp"=>"1320837649", "data"=>"\"content_hash\"", "auth"=>"auth_string"}
```

I am not able to figure it out why socky is not able to send data to browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the channel name is to long :(

I just had the same error trying to make a channel name with **33** characters.. but when i shortened it to **24** it worked fine.

I hope that helps.